# Overload stored procedure in DB2

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, db2

I know, it is possible to overload PLSQL functions and procedures in ORACLE. 
I tried to overload a procedure in DB2 but was throwing error. Does DB2 restrict this or am I doing something wrong.

**Pro 1**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  saju_pro (
     s_num1      IN     NUMBER,
     s_num2      IN OUT     NUMBER )
AS
BEGIN
    s_num2 := (s_num1+s_num2);
END saju_pro;
/
```

**PRO2**

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE  saju_pro (
     s_num1      IN     NUMBER,
     s_num2      IN     NUMBER,
     s_num3      OUT     NUMBER  )
AS
BEGIN
    s_num3 := (s_num1+s_num2);
END saju_pro;
```

Comment: How is java relevant with this question?

Comment: @nakosspy  I was using JDBC to fetch its metadata. Added in it effect. 
:) Removed!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to overload procedures in DB2. There are two ways of doing this. One would be to declare and define the procedures as part of a PL/SQL package:

```
create or replace package body blah
as
  PROCEDURE  saju_pro (
    s_num1      IN     NUMBER,
    s_num2      IN OUT     NUMBER )
  AS
  ...
  PROCEDURE  saju_pro (
    s_num1      IN     NUMBER,
    s_num2      IN     NUMBER,
    s_num3      OUT     NUMBER  )
  AS
  ...
end;
```

If you really want standalone procedures, you must create them using the DB2 SQL PL syntax, not PL/SQL syntax, because only using the SQL PL syntax you can use the SPECIFIC option to let DB2 distinguish the two.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  saju_pro (
 IN    s_num1   NUMBER,
 INOUT s_num2   NUMBER )
SPECIFIC pro1
BEGIN
 SET s_num2 = (s_num1+s_num2);
END;
-- etc.
```

Comment: Thank You. I was using the **syscat.routineparms** to get the procedure definition metadata. COuld you please tell me how to identify if a procedure is overloaded or not, using this table??

Comment: How would you identify if a procedure is overloaded or not **not** using any tables? You can apply the same logic.

Comment: well, i need to determine it in runtime using java. So how could this not **not** logic work?

Comment: Abstract yourself for a moment from Java or syscat.routineparms. How would you, a person, describe overloaded procedures to me, a person? Anyway, overloaded procedures would have the same ROUTINENAME and different SPECIFICNAMEs in SYSCAT.ROUTINES.